# Conditional formatting on a list on sharepoint 2013 using CSR

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to get conditional formatting to work on a list on Sharepoint 2013, what i want it do to is to change the colour of the words in the priority field depending on what is inputted e.g. High = red Low = Green Med = orange

I've tried multiple ways of doing this and i've looked at a lot of tutorials but as i only have a basic knowledge of JS and CSR i'm finding it very hard, i understand to make a JS file apply to a web part i have to link the address location of the file in the miscellanious area of the web part editor it's just the code i'm having issues with.

Here's what i have so far

```js
 
(function () { 

    var priorityFiledContext = {}; 
    priorityFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        
        "Priority": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate } 
    }; 
 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext); 
 
})(); 

function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) { 
 
    var priority = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 
  
    switch (priority) { 
        case "(1) High": 
            return "<span style='color :#f00'>" + priority + "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "(2) Normal": 
            return "<span style='color :#ff6a00'>" + priority + "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "(3) Low": 
            return "<span style='color :#cab023'>" + priority + "</span>"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd can you explain better the issue you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good as long as you're using English standard task lists (if not, you would have to change the priority strings in the switch block to whatever your task list is using).

You can simplify deploying CSR customizations using e.g. the Cisar Chrome browser plugin. It publishes changes written in a browser window in real time to the server attaching an on-the-fly created Javascript file to the list currently opened in the browser (supposing you have permissions to do so).